# Spacemacs warnings after upgrade Debian 10 to 11 on Chromebook

Tags: emacs, debian, google-chrome-os, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs on a Chromebook using the Linux environment. I had a notification indicated me that a new version of Debian was available, and I launched the upgrade. After that, when launching emacs with Spacemacs, it is written

> found 6 new package(s) to install ...
> refreshing package archive: nongnu [/]

After a few time, there is the following warnings:

`Error (use-package): hl-todo/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: global-hl-todo-mode`

`Error (use-package): undo-tree/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: global-undo-tree-mode`

It looks like I can continue to use emacs/spacemacs normally, but it took a certain time to launch.

Comment: when I try to undo an action, it doesn't work and I have the following message : `evil-undo: Symbol’s function definition is void: undo-tree-undo`

Comment: open spacemacs today, and new package installation went good. Had the following messages :
`Found 6 new package(s) to install...
--> refreshing package archive: nongnu... [4/4]
--> installing package: undo-tree@spacemacs-editing... [6/6]`

No more problems with undo function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something related to updating keys. Try updating gnu-elpa-keyring-update. Here is the command "M-x package-install RET gnu-elpa-keyring-update RET"

https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/gnu-elpa-keyring-update.html